# set session in page_load

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, authentication

I've a page width this code in a page a called Log.aspx:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Session.Abandon();
    Session.Clear();
    string username = "a";
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
    {
        db_user = db.CBR_User
            .Include("CBR_MissioniGruppi")
            .Include("Anagrafica_Dipendente.Extra_dipendente")
            .Include("Anagrafica_Dipendente.Dati_Dipendente")
            .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Anagrafica_Dipendente.Extra_Dipendente.Codice_Fiscale.Equals(username, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        Session["User"] = db_user;
        Session["t_admin"] = null;
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
    }
}
```

The problem is that if i launch 2 times the page with 2 username differents 
in Default.aspx page the second time a read the variable Session["User"] saved in the first time.

es.

```
1)Launch Log.aspx with username = "a"
-> the session["User"] in Default page has the user with username a
2) Launch Log.aspx with username = "n"
-> the session["User"] in Default page has the user with username a
```

Why?

I've seen that if i put a button in log page and i excute the procedure on click event, it works.

How can i do to fix it?

thanks

Comment: I think that what your asking and what your code is actually doing are two very, very different things. It's also not clear how your code _should_ be performing.

Answer (score 0):

It's not not completely clear what you're asking here.  Looking at your code, you're hard coding the value of username to 'a', so it will always be 'a'.

```
string username = "a";
```

If that's not your problem, I would imagine you have some sort of race condition where your multiple reads/writes to the Session are causing conflict.